# Hdfs folder size in Clojure

Tags: java, clojure, hdfs, clojurescript, clojure-java-interop

I have to HDFS folder size which is having sub directories from Clojure. How to use getContentSummary and getSpaceConsumed in Clojure. I know how to do this in Java.

```
 FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(config);
 Path current = new Path(path);
 double size= fs.getContentSummary(current).getSpaceConsumed();
```

Configuration has been set already and path is passed into this function. So size now has has the size of the directory mentioned as path. This is in Java. I want to know how to do this in Clojure.

Thanks.

Comment: Please add more infos and some code. Show us what you already tried

Comment: Done. I want to know how to implement the third line of my code in Clojure.

Comment: You mean: `(-> (.getContentSummary current) .getSpaceConsumed)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you "just" need to follow the [java interop guide](http://clojure.org/reference/java_interop):

```
(let [fs (FileSystem/get config)
      current (Path. path)
      size (.getSpaceConsumed (.getContentSummary fs current))]
  (println size))
```

Or using the "->" macro, to make it read more like Java:

```
(let [fs (FileSystem/get config)
      current (Path. path)
      size (-> fs (.getContentSummary current) .getSpacedConsumed)]
  (println size))
```